# R - load multiple csv files and drop .csv from name

Tags: r, for-loop, substr, read.csv

I have some files in a base directory that I use to house all my .csv files

```
base_dir <- file.path(path)
file_list <- list.files(path = base_dir, pattern = "*.csv")
```

I would like to load all of them at once:

```
for (i in 1:length(file_list)){
  assign(file_list[i],
  read.csv(paste(base_dir, file_list[i], sep = ""))

)}
```

However, this produces files with ".csv" in the names in R.

What I would like to do is load all the files but drop the ".csv" from the name once they are loaded.

I have tried the following:

```
 for (i in 1:length(file_list)){ assign(file_list[i],
 read.csv(substr(paste(base_dir, file_list[i], sep = ""), 1,
 nchar(file_list[i]) -4))
 
 )}
```

But I received an error:  `No such file or directory`

Is there a way to do this somewhat efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub` to remove the `.csv` at the end

```
for (i in 1:length(file_list)){
  assign(sub("\\.csv$", "", basename(file_list[i])),
       read.csv(paste(base_dir, file_list[i], sep = ""))

    )}
```

---

Or another option is `file_path_sans_ext`

```
for (i in 1:length(file_list)){
  assign(tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(file_list[i])),
       read.csv(paste(base_dir, file_list[i], sep = ""))

    )}
```

---

The error produced in OP's code is because the `substr` is applied on the 'value' part i.e. the one goes into reading the file instead of the 'x' i.e. the corrected code would be

```
for(i in 1:length(file_list)){       
     assign(substr(paste(base_dir, file_list[i], sep = ""), 
           1, nchar(file_list[i]) -4),     
         read.csv(file_list[i])

 )}
```

---

Also, if the working directory is different, it may be better to specify `full.names = TRUE`

```
file_list <- list.files(path = base_dir, pattern = "*\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4):

Normally one reads them into a list rather than having them as free objects floating around in the workspace.  Use `dir` or `Sys.glob` to generate the full path names and then use `read.csv` to read each one in.   L's names will be pathnames so reduce them to the basename and remove .csv .

```
# paths <- dir(path = path, pattern = "\\.csv$", full = TRUE)
paths <- Sys.glob(sprintf("%s/*.csv", path))
L <- Map(read.csv, paths)
names(L) <- sub("\\.csv$", "", basename(names(L)))
```

If you really want them as free floating objects anyways then add this:

```
list2env(L, .GlobalEnv)
```